# Problem with sitemap.xml in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, sitemap

I have Ruby on Rails app and I created **sitemap.xml** file (in public directory) with **sitemap_generator** gem but it can't be readable in production.

**sitemap.rb**

```
# Set the host name for URL creation
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "https://example.com"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.namer = SitemapGenerator::SimpleNamer.new(:sitemap, :extension => '.xml')

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

  Category.find_each do |cat|
    add category_path(cat), priority: 0.8, changefreq: 'daily', lastmod: cat.updated_at
  end

  Job.where(status: true).find_each do |job|
    add job_path(job), priority: 0.6, lastmod: job.updated_at
  end

end
```

**errors_controller.rb**

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def not_found
    render status: 404
  end

  def unprocessable_entity
    render status: 422
  end

  def internal_server_error
    render status: 500
  end

end
```

I have all views for each kind of errors but **Heroku logs** show me:

```
I, [2019-10-16T11:57:53 #4]  INFO -- : Processing by ErrorsController#not_found as XML
I, [2019-10-16T11:57:53 #4]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2019-10-16T11:57:53 app[web.1]: Error during failsafe response: Missing template errors/not_found, application/not_found with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
2019-10-16T11:57:53 app[web.1]: * "/app/app/views"
```

The command **heroku run rails sitemap:refresh:no_ping** is creating all links that I want but when I try to see the link https://mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml - I get 500 error and I can't see the content - I don't know why. I think it can be some problems with error controller because https://mywebsite.com/sitemap (without .xml) displays 404 page. With .xml it is 500 error.

On localhost everything works fine but in production mode on Heroku I have problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, sitemap_generator creates sitemap.xml.gz file. Try open `your-site.com/sitemap.xml.gz`. Works on my project.